# Вставка в монго через for

Tags: node.js, javascript

Есть функция для втавки в монго:

```
function insert_to_mdb (db_data) {
var mdb_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/DB';
mongodb.connect(mdb_url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
    db.collection('test').insert(db_data, function(err, records) {
        if (err) throw err;    
        db.close();
    });
});
}
```

Далее пробую

```
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
var test_json_str = {'DATA': '123456' };
    insert_to_mdb(test_json_str);
};
```

И получаю

```
mongo_client.js:409
      throw err
            ^
Error: connection closed
```

Причём это только на больших вставках, как я понимаю, просто кончаются пул или свободные соеденения к БД. Как с этим можно бороться?

Comment: Половина вопроса решена, цикл for блокирует nextTick в libuv, но вопрос, как сбросить все подключения всё равно актуален.

Answer (score 1):

[callback - callback function to run after the record is inserted](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html), а это значит, что ты закрыл коннект после первого insert-a.

Comment: но в ф-ции есть новый коннект, к тому же если дело было бы в коннекте, то она бы вообще не вставляла большое кол-во, а она не может вставить, если for больше 100, на 50-ти работает 50/50

Comment: По хорошему, нужно соединяться с базой лишь однажды, а не внутри цикла. Функция асинхронная, и когда новый коннект открыт, старый вызов может его закрыть. В общем, у вас в коде довольно конфликтная ситуация.

Comment: @vnn198, ты закомментируй close и посмотрим

Comment: ну тогда приложение не закроется, ибо висит открытая связб с монго

Comment: @vnn198, закроется

Comment: @vnn198 по идее, может и должен. А может возвращает тот же инстанс, если он находит его в пуле. Все таки таже база данных. Это имеет смысл проверить. И все же не соединяться с базой в цикле. Вы тестируете mongodb?

Comment: ну так ведь не закрывается :)

Comment: @zhenyab я тестирую массовую вставку через мою ф-цию, просто, for хорошо подходит для генерации большого кол-ва запросов, ну и заодно хотел понять предел по кол-ву вставок для БД, ибо у меня 32-bit и предел для базы 2gb. Заодно хотелось понять, сколько я могу хранить там записей